# Javascript function runs from HTML event but fails from an IF statement

Tags: javascript, html

I ran this function when I click off the username input:

```
function checkUsername(){
    if($("#signupUsername").val()!=""){
        $.post("checkUsername.php",$("#signupForm :input").serializeArray(),function(data){
            if(data){
                $("#signupUsernameOutput").text("Username Taken");
                $("#signupUsernameOutput").css("color","#CE0000");
                return false;       
            }
            else{
                $("#signupUsernameOutput").text("Username OK");
                $("#signupUsernameOutput").css("color","green");                
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        $("#signupUsernameOutput").text("");
        return false;   
    }
}
```

using:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="checkUsername()" placeholder="Username" name="signupUsername" id="signupUsername">
```

My issue I need to run the same function later on from an If statement it doesn't work. Does anyone know why?:

```
if(checkUsername()==true){
       alert("success!");
       //and some other stuff...
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `)`. Is that in your original code or just a copying error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: apologies as Barmar pointed out there was a copy error which I have corrected

Comment: How can you accidentally remove a bracket from the middle of your code when pasting it here?

Comment: if(checkUsername()==true)     equals is redundant :) it's just code style suggestion.

Comment: I was performing another check in the if statement. but it's unrelated to the issue. I have tested as pasted above.

Comment: I did think ==true was pointless doing but it wasnt returning as expected so I shoved it in there for the luls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are calling sends an asynchronous AJAX request. That is not going to work. It will get the AJAX request ready to go, and then it will return `undefined`, it will not return true in any situation.

You may want to think about changing your code, and adding code for a "promise".  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you forgot a `)`, the function that executes when `$.post()` is complete is Asynchronous, so at the time you call `checkUsername` the completion function has not fired. Additionally you would be returning `true` or `false` to that function, not `checkUsername`. In short, everything has to happen inside your completion function, and it won't do any good to return anything. You can, however, change HTML inside the completion function.